# Есть ли здесь однородные обстоятельства? 2

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая?

...расположение на первом, самом опасном цикле подвижной группы ПК (,) в стороне от критического и кавитирующего турбулентного потока рабочей среды, вызывающего вибрации и удары...

Comment: А где Вы видите однородные обстоятельства? Расположение какое?-на самом...  Обстоятельство относится к сказуемому, а это  несогласованное определение. Нужно было весь контекст дать, со сказуемым. Собственно, дело только в термине, запятая всё равно нужна.

Comment: Я думала, расположение где?..

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что запятая нужна. Это идут два уточняющих оборота.
На первом - каком именно? - самом опасном цикле, на самом опасном - каком именно? (их может быть несколько...) - в стороне от критического и кавитирующего потока рабочей среды. Таким образом, мы постепенно уточняем круг нахождения данного явления, сужая и сужая его.
 Таких уточнений может быть несколько. И каждое из них обособляется с двух сторон.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что запятая нужна. Хотя это разные обстоятельства, но их можно считать **сближенными и поэтому однородными**, так как они раскрывают общую картину расположения.

Постановке запятой способствует и **распространенность** обстоятельств.